# Android touch input NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a car racing game . In this game I have made two Buttons and attached scripts `carController` to its `EventTrigger` on pointer down as follows :

[CAR gameobject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42gm3.png)

the car controller script is in c# and is as follows:

```
public class carController : MonoBehaviour {
         public float carSpeed;
         Vector3 position;
         public uiManager ui;
         public audioManager am;
      Rigidbody2D rb;
         bool currentPlatformAndroid=false;
         // Use this for initialization

         void awake(){

             rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
             #if  UNITY_ANDROID
             currentPlatformAndroid=true;
             #else
             currentPlatformAndroid=false;
             #endif
             am.carSound.Play ();

         }


         void Start () {
             //ui = GetComponent<uiManager> (); no need

             if (currentPlatformAndroid == true) {

                 Debug.Log ("Android");
             } else {
                 Debug.Log ("windows");
             }

             position = transform.position;
         }

         // Update is called once per frame
         void Update () {
             if (currentPlatformAndroid == true) {
                 //android specific
                 TouchMove();

             } else {
                 position.x+=Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                 position.x= Mathf.Clamp (position.x, -2.1f, 2.1f);
                 transform.position = position;
             }
             position = transform.position;
             position.x= Mathf.Clamp (position.x, -2.1f, 2.1f);
             transform.position = position;



         }

         void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){

             if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy Car") {
                 gameObject.SetActive (false);
                 ui.gameOverF ();
                 am.carSound.Stop ();
             }

         }

         public void MoveLeft(){
             rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-carSpeed, 0);
         }

         public void MoveRight(){
             rb.velocity = new Vector2 (carSpeed, 0);
         }

         public void SetVelocityZero(){

             rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
         }

         void TouchMove(){
             if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
                 Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);
                 float middle=Screen.width/2;
                 if (touch.position.x < middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                     MoveLeft ();
                 }
                 else if((touch.position.x > middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)){
                     MoveRight();
                 }



                     }else{
                         SetVelocityZero();
                     }



         }


     }
```

Now I have tried both button touch and swipe touch but both are not working !!

It is giving this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPOTu.png)

Am I am not able to figure out why ?

Can anybody help ?

Mainly the error log is as follows :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
carController.SetVelocityZero () (at Assets/scripts/carController.cs:78)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:153)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:634)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:769)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1[T0].Invoke (.T0 arg0) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_1.cs:53)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.Execute (EventTriggerType id, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/EventTrigger.cs:67)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnPointerUp (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/EventTrigger.cs:98)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerUpHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerUpHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

and line of code is this :

```
public void MoveLeft(){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-carSpeed, 0);
    }

    public void MoveRight(){
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (carSpeed, 0);
    }

    public void SetVelocityZero(){

        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
```

**Carspeed** is also initalised as follows :

`carspeed=4` in editor as it is public

Comment: you get a NullReferenceException, so please post the error log

Comment: as image above @Opiatefuchs

Comment: Which line of code?

Comment: cs 73 and 78 line of code @Programmer

Comment: as well as cs 69 line of code too @Programmer

Comment: Please edit and post that line of code for both of the error

Comment: `carspeed` is not initialized....

Comment: It is @Opiatefuchs see image

Answer (score 0):

`rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();` is failing because there is no `Rigidbody2D` attached to the GameObject the script is attached to.

Please attach `Rigidbody2D` to that GameObject the `carController` script is attached to.

You can also replace

`rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();`

with

`GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectRigidBody2DIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();`

if you don't want to attach the `carController` script to that GameObject with `Rigidbody2D`.

Comment: Rigidbody2D is attached as the script is attached to `car` game object

Comment: see  1st image I have linked above @Programmer

Comment: Look and make sure that you don;t have `carController` script attached to another GameObject.

Comment: No it is only attached to `car` game Obj

Comment: This is very awkward behaviour ! Normal pc input works but android touch button  doesn't ! Is there any problem in the `function` itself ?

Comment: To do that, right click on the` carController` script and click "Find References In Scene". There is nothing wrong with those functions.

Comment: there are three reference : **car** game object, **left** and **right** touch buttons only

Comment: But you said there was only one reference....That's the problem. Look at my my answer. You can either remove `carController` from other cars if it doesn't need to be attached to them or you MUST attach `Rigidbody2D` to each of the Objects that has the script attached to them.

Comment: even with Ui buttons ?

Comment: Yes, I think that you should watch Unity tutorials before going further with your Game so that you will know how to structure your game. By your questions, I don't think you are ready to do that. You will run into more problems. What does the left and right touch buttons  do? Do you press and hold them or do  you just press them?

Comment: I press and hold them bcoz I want continuous motion

Comment: thats why I uesd event trigger

Comment: Then what happens? What do those buttons do? Can you post a screenshot of what is attached to them?

Comment: those button when i touch and hold **SHOULD** move car left and right on  android  and I have attached gameobject `car` to that event trigger on pointer down  component